# How to get loaded web page title in SFSafariViewController?

Tags: sfsafariviewcontroller

How to get loaded web page title in SFSafariViewController?

I am using below these delegate to get the url but it doesnt call when i am pressing **Action button**

```
func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, activityItemsFor URL: URL, title: String?) -> [UIActivity] {
  let my activity = UIActivity()
  let name =  myactivity.activityTitle}
```

Comment: https://github.com/koogawa/SFSafariViewControllerSample/blob/master/SFSafariViewControllerSample/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to set the delegate? Ex: `safariViewController.delegate = self` ?

Comment: yeah i added.
safariViewControllerDidFinish,didCompleteInitialLoad those delegates are working fine. when i click done button.